# Not saving over template

Tags: excel, apache, apache-poi

I have an XLS template which I am modifying via Apache POI.

The aim is to modify the template and then email this modified xls spreadsheet.

Once the workbook has been modified accordingly - is there a way to keep this file in memory without saving over the original

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("template.xls"));
//do some processing
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("template.xls");
wb.write();
fileOut.close();
```

I want to keep this template in tact for the next run. I would have used Apache freemarker but couldnt see xls support.

Comment: Don't use a `FileOutputStream` if you don't want to save to a file???

Comment: @Gagravarr yes - but what other mechanism then is there to take the POISFileSystem to a new file?

Comment: Any other `OutputStream` you want, eg `ByteArrayOutputStream`